# My PS3 wont connect to the T.V. or the controller?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

Last night my PS3 was working fine, and now it won't connect with the controller or the HDMI port, but it turns on. When I turn it on, I have to hold the power button just for it to turn off.

Also yesterday while my Mom was watching Netflix on my PS3 my little brother came and tugged on the chord that was plugged into the PS3 and it fell on to the ground sideways, I think that could just be the problem but just in case I'm wrong and there is something wrong with it, do you guys think you guys can tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: I would start by making sure all the connections are secure to the TV and back of the PS3 (due to tugging and falling of the device). Second I would make sure the PS3 controller hasn't run out of battery. If the controller doesn't turn the system on with the USB cable attached then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: Yeah the controller doesn't turn on the Ps3, do you know what that means?

Comment: @Kevinyang Make sure your PS3 controller is **plugged in for charging state** as you try to turn it on.

Comment: It wont connect to the ps3 either.

Answer (score 3):

Unplug all of the cables and plug them back in again.
If there is still no action, plug the controller into the PS3 using its USB adapter.

If the playstation makes more than 1 beep when you turn it on, that means there is an issue.

If it does 3 beeps with a flashing red light and then turns off again, that means that it thinks it's overheating. Which means that the bump might have shifted something inside the machine.

If it simply turns on with a green light as normal, I'd say it's definitely an issue with the connections .

make sure the TV is on the correct channel, make sure the controller has power by plugging it in, make sure all cables are plugged in to the TV and the PlayStation firmly by replacing them.

If you're still having trouble, send us a reply!

Comment: it turns on normally but I can only turn  it off by holding the power button. And when it's on hdmi 2 it shows up as 480 under the sign that shows what channel I'm on then it loses connection. Sorry I'm not the best at explaining things.

Comment: You could try using a Scart cable and using the AV channel on the TV. Or using a Composite cable. Other than that I'd say have a look on Google and YouTube dude. It's hard to diagnose with such little information

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your batteries are not dead in the remote first. If the remote is not dead and it still wont connect then try plugging in the USB, if that still wont work then it might be the remote or the system. Now for the HDMI connecting issue, If you tweaked any of the display settings that might be the problem but if you have not then try making sure the connector are clean and that they are plugged in nice and snug. If you are still net getting a display then is might be the HDMI cable or the system. If none of these fix your problem i would contacts Sony, You can chat with them by phone or by chat online. [Click Here For Sony Support](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/contact_options) I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: I cant see the menu of the Ps3 at all, only the ps3 works, and the controller doesn't turn on the Ps3 anymore